# Most efficient way to return array of struct member

Tags: c++, candlestick-chart

I have a struct like:

```
struct ohlc{
    double open,high,low,close;
};
```

Part of my application makes use of a collection of these.  Sometimes time-stamped.  Another part of my app uses a third party (closed) library that requires arrays of doubles e.g. close[] or open[] etc.

What would be the most suitable container and method to return a double array of open[], close[] etc.  Currently, I use vector and iterate over the whole collection to create the arrays.  Is there a more efficient way.

I may even be completely wrong with my current use of the struct?  What I have is a price feed of bid/ask prices.  I try to maintain a collection of M1, M5, M15 and H1 candle sticks i.e. OHLC data.  Typically I only require 100 hrs worth of data.  As a new minute of prices comes in, I can delete the oldest minute thus maintaining 100 hrs worth of data at any time.  As the H1, M15, M5, M1 can all be created from the base data of time-stamped ask/bid prices, do I still need to hold independent H1, M15 etc for performance reasons.  I ask this because it is a duplication of data?

EDIT:  My current method is fine for my usual purpose but now I am 'back-testing', I'm throwing millions of bid/ask prices at my code and need it to be as efficient as possible.  The back tests can currently take hours to perform

I return from my collection of structs as follows:

```
std::vector<double> Series::EODSeries::open( const_iterator iter, unsigned long num ) const
{
  vector<double> v;

  if( iter == end() )
    return v;

  // reverse iterator init skips the first element in collection. We must manually insert the current element.
  v.insert(v.begin(), iter->second.open);
  unsigned i = 1;
  for( const_reverse_iterator rev_iter(iter); i < num && rev_iter != rend(); ++rev_iter, ++i )
    v.insert(v.begin(), rev_iter->second.open);

  return v; 
}
```

Comment: How are you returning the vector, and do the callers need to own a copy of it? Do they need to be able to write to it? Maybe a code snippet showing how you get an array out of the vector and pass it on to the 3rd party API would help.

Comment: will add example to my original

Answer (score 3):

You say the third party application requires arrays of doubles but this is slightly misleading since arrays cannot be arguments in C++ – they always decay to pointers.

So what you can do is simply pass a pointer to the first argument of your vector. This is guaranteed to work.

```
// Assuming the following signature:
void the_method(double arg[]);
// is actually the same as:
// void the_method(double* arg);

std::vector<double> open; // your vector
the_method(&open[0]);
```

However, if I misunderstood you and you actually have a `std::vector<ohlc>` then you are essentially out of luck – you indeed need to copy the `open` and `close` members out of this vector’s elements into its own container. But even here I’d advise you to use a *`vector`* in your code, not a C array.

Comment: Good point about vector vs c array.  I should have remembered that I can use a vector that way.  I will try with passing the vectors.